# Drupal Webform hook_webform_submission_insert not firing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to use the hook_webform_submission_insert in my theme template.php file. I have 2 other webform hooks currently running in here and they work just fine. I am trying to get the submission data after it has been submitted. Below is my code.

```
function acquarius_hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission){
    var_dump($node);
    var_dump($submission);
}
```

I am sure I am missing something small here but everything I try seems to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace hook keyword with your theme name. Also add hook functions in module.

```
    YOURTHEMENAME_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission){
// give your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create a new hook, you need to clear the drupal caches.

Go to YOURSITE.com/admin/config/development/performance

And click on "Clear all caches"